# Verify gpg key from stdin

Tags: ubuntu, apt, docker, gpg, apt-key

I'm using these commands in a `Dockerfile` to add the [LLVM Ubuntu package repository](https://apt.llvm.org/):

```
RUN echo deb http://apt.llvm.org/artful/ llvm-toolchain-artful-6.0 main > \
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/llvm.list && \
    wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | apt-key add -
```

This will add the repository and register the key. However, I'd also like to verify the key using the fingerprint given on the website. How can I extend this command to verify the key?

Answer (score 0):

The command to validate gpg fingerprints is `gpg --with-fingerprint --with-colons -`.

Thus, first you download the key and then pipe it into the gpg validator.

```
wget -qO- https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | gpg --with-fingerprint --with-colons -
wget -qO- https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | gpg --with-fingerprint --with-colons - | sed -ne 's|^fpr:::::::::\([0-9A-F]\+\):$|\1|p'
```

Note, the full secure solution would require you to guarantee to validate the fingerprint of *the same key* what you actually decrypt.

Comment: I improved the answer, I hope there is no need to delete it any more. Helló Viktor! :-)